# io.micrometer.core.instrument.config.MeterFilter : DENY is not working in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer

I want to expose all metrics on the metrics endpoint but publish some of them to a remote meter registry.

For doing so, I have a SimpleMeterRegistry for the metrics endpoint and added a *MeterRegistryCustomizer* for the remote meter registry(Datadog) to add some *MeterFilter* to avoid specific metrics using *MeterFilter's DENY* function. For example :

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<StatsdMeterRegistry> meterRegistryCustomizer() {
    return (registry) -> new StatsdMeterRegistry(config, Clock.SYSTEM).config().meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("jvm"));
   }
```

However, all jvm related metrics are visible in Datadog. I tried *MeterFilterReply* but no use.
Please suggest how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You are configuring the filter on a new `StatsdMeterRegistry`. When using a `MeterRegistryCustomizer` you need to operate on the registry that was passed in.

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<StatsdMeterRegistry> meterRegistryCustomizer() {
    return (registry) -> registry.config().meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("jvm"));
   }
```

Since the customizer will be used against all registries, you also would need to add an if statement to only filter against the registry you want filtered.

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<StatsdMeterRegistry> meterRegistryCustomizer() {
   return (registry) -> { 
      if(registry instanceof StatsdMeterRegistry) {
        registry.config().meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("jvm"));
      }   
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @checketts. I tried your solution but it removes all jvm related metrics from actuator endpoint as well. However, I also came across aged-out period in datadog Ui which is 24 hours for all metrics.

Comment: Below code worked for me:     ```@Bean
    public MeterRegistry meterRegistry() {
        CompositeMeterRegistry registry = new CompositeMeterRegistry();
        registry.add(new SimpleMeterRegistry());
        return registry;
    }

    @Bean
    public MeterRegistryCustomizer<StatsdMeterRegistry> meterRegistryCustomizer() {
        return (registry) -> registry.config().meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("jvm"));
    }```